# map vs filter in Apache Spark

Tags: apache-spark

From official documentation for Apache Spark:

http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/rdd-programming-guide.html

> map(func):Return a new **distributed dataset** formed by passing each element of the source through a function func.
>
> filter(func)  Return a new **dataset** formed by selecting those elements of the source on which func returns true.

Going by bold words, is it a big difference?And is it really a difference?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They serve different purposes. If we look at the (simplified) method definition for `map`:

```
def map[U](func: (T) ⇒ U): Dataset[U]
```

expects that given an element of type `T`, you yield an element of type `U`, forall `T`, resulting in a `Dataset[U]`. In other words, a means of transforming an element of type `T` to type `U`.

On the other hand, `filter`:

```
def filter(func: (T) ⇒ Boolean): Dataset[T]
```

expects that given an element of type `T`, you provide a `Boolean` value which says if that given element should be yielded back in the resulting `Dataset[T]` or not (often refereed to as a [Predicate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Predicate_(mathematical_logic))).

A concrete example of `map` can be:

```
val someDataSet: DataSet[String] = ???
val transformedDataSet: DataSet[Int] = someDataSet.map(str => str.toInt)
```

And for filter:

```
val someDataSet: DataSet[String] = ???
val transformedDataSet: DataSet[String] = someDataSet.filter(str => str.length > 5)
```

Comment: what Scala and Spark version do you use? In the version that I use (2.4.0 spark, 2.11.1 Scala), the `filter` method does not accept a function.

Comment: @scarface Are you sure you're looking at the right place? https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.4.0/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset@filter(func:T=%3EBoolean):org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset[T]

Comment: You are right. Actually I was using Code With Me plugin in Intellij IDEA and it was bugged and not showing me all the methods. Thanks.

Comment: simple and clean,thanks

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov, so sorry, yes mistakenly, does not allow me to correct it :(

Answer (score 5):

It's really just a difference from the end-user in how you use the API. `map` is meant to take a record as input and return a record that you've applied some function to. Whereas `filter` is meant to take a record as input and return a boolean. Internally Spark will execute both with `mapPartitions`.

Answer (score 0):

Think the whole RDD as a pipeline where you throw apples, bananas and peaches, then in the pipeline, you have a filter that only allow go through apple [filter], so then you have just apple, and then you want to transform an apple into a candy apple applying some sugar [map]

So you start with apples, bananas and peaches and you end up producing candy apples.